# A list of Microsoft Updates Applicable to Windows Server 2019 (LTSC) since release

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2019

I would like to generate a list of Microsoft Updates (security etc.) that are applicable to Windows Server 2019 (LTSC) since its release. Is there an easy way of doing this on the Windows Update website?

Answer (score 1):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4537818/windows-10-update-kb4537818

It's in the lower part of the left pane.

[image: Windows Server 2019 Updates]